# Pytorch - Subclasses of torchvision.dataset.ImageFolder - Import Error

Tags: python, python-import, pytorch

Following my last [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798172/pytorch-how-to-make-the-trainloader-use-a-specific-amount-of-images), I am now trying to implement a subclass of the `torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder` class. The following code returns an error (`"name 'default_loader' is not defined"`), and I can't figure out why. Will you please help me?

```
class ExtendingImageFolder(torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder)
   def __init__(self,root,transform=None, target_transform=None,loader=default_loader):
       super().__init__(root,transform,target_transform,loader)
```

When I delete the "`None`" and "`default_loader`", and write it like this;

```
    class ExtendingImageFolder(torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder)
   def __init__(self,root,transform, target_transform,loader):
       super().__init__(root,transform,target_transform,loader)
```

I get an error of missing input arguments when trying to create an instance of this class, like:

```
JJ=ExtendingImageFolder(root='C:/',transform=transform)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`default_loader()` is a function defined in [`torchvision/datasets/folder.py`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/datasets/folder.py#L168), along `ImageFolder` and other folder-based dataset helpers.

It is however not exported in [`torchvision/datasets/__init__.py`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/datasets/__init__.py#L13) (unlike `ImageFolder`). You can still import it directly with "`from torchvision.datasets.folder import default_loader`" - which should solve your import error.

Comment: Thanks Aldream, I will try it later today. But - when I define a subclass if ImageFolder, shouldn't the subclass inherit all the functions and methods defined in ImageFolder?

Comment: Right, but `default_loader()` isn't a method of the `ImageFolder` class, it is just a helper function placed in the same file.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!